# RegisterStartupScript is clearing cookie

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working in ASP.Net 2.0 application. In one page, I have a button. On click of the button, I'm calling below two functions.  OpenPopup function will open the url in pop up window and RedirectToApp function will redirect the current page to hoomepage. But it is opening homepage with errors and redirecting to login page automatically. If I comment OpenPopup function, it is working fine. I think OpenPopup function is clearing the cookie which I'm using for home page. Please guide me to solve this problem.

```
private void OpenPopup(url){
  string s="window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=900,height=800,scrollbars,resizable');";
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
}

private void RedirectToApp(string url){
  string s = @"<script language='javascript'> 
        window.location.replace('"+url + @"');
        </script>";
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mfRedirectScript", s);
}
```